# New Project/Campaign set up in CiviCRM

Tags: civicampaign

I've set up a number of projects/campaigns on CiviCRM so we can record donations against them and clearly see how much has been raised against each project.  However, I need to set up a new project and the look of the system has changed since I last did it so I can't work out how to do it. I'd be so grateful for some advice!

Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

1/ you might need to add a screenshot to your Question so folk can see what you are seeing

2/ you could visit https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/dashboard and compare what you are seeing with what the Demo site shows

3/ you could visit https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/menu?reset=1 and compare what the Navigation Menu looks like there compared to yours